# Перегрузка оператора []

Tags: c++

```
class test {

    int **mass;
    int i;
    int j;

public:

    test(int i, int j) {
        this->i = i;
        this->j = j;

        mass = new int*[i];

        for (int k=0; k<i; k++) {
            mass[k] = new int[j];
        }

    }

    int &operator[](int n) {
        return mass[n];
    }

};
```

Как правильно написать перегруженую функцию [], чтобы получить доступ к елементу матрицы? Например: cout << obj[0][0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае достаточно просто заменить:

```
int &operator[](int n) {
    return mass[n];
}
```

на:

```
int* operator[](int n) {
    return mass[n];
}
```

**UPD:** Еще можно возвращать proxy-объект, который в свою очередь будет давать доступ к строке. Заодно проверять входные параметры. Что-то вроде такого:

```
class test {
    int **mass;
    int i;
    int j;

public:
    class RowProxy {
    public:
         RowProxy(int* data, int length)
             : data(data),
               length(length)
         {}

         int& operator[](int n) {
              if (n >= length) throw std::invalid_argument("No such column");
              return data[n];
         }
    private:
        int* data;
        int length;
    };

    test(int i, int j) {
        this->i = i;
        this->j = j;

        mass = new int*[i];

        for (int k=0; k<i; k++) {
            mass[k] = new int[j];
        }

    }

    RowProxy operator[](int n) {
        if (n >= i) throw std::invalid_argument("No such row");
        return RowProxy(mass[n], j);
    }
};
```

Comment: спасибо=) может ищё какие-нибудь способы хитрые исть этой реализации ?

Comment: Плохо передавать наружу указатель на свои данные.

Comment: @Aндрей, а что плохого. Например std::vector передает наружу ссылку на свои данные.

Comment: Если уж ООП, то было бы хорошо придумать что-нибудь по-изящнее, чтобы за пределы массива не уйти и т.д. На досуге можно будет подумать, тем более тут передо мной подобная задача маячит.

Comment: @dzhioev указатель и ссылка -- вещи немного разные.

Comment: Немного разные, но по сути одно и то же. Тот же самый вектор не очень-то безопасен:
    
    int* ptr = &vec[0];
    *(ptr + 5) = 10; //изменяем значение в 5-ом элементе
    free(ptr); // так делать не стоит

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать лучше:

```
class test
{
    int* mass;
    int i, j;

public:
    test(int i, int j)
    {
        this->i=i, this->j=j;
        mass=new int[i*j];
    }

    int* operator[](int n)
    {
        return mass+n*i;
    }
};
```